# Setting a variable with URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-hosting

I have deployed a firebase site which works fine. The problem I have is the next:
Inside my `main.js` I have a variable called `company`. Is there a way to set that variable depending on the `URL`? For example:

```
site-ce207.firebaseapp.com/company=01
```

Or do you know another way?

Comment: Yes, however the example you've used, won't work. Using `http://www.example.com/#company=01` or `http://www.example.com/?company=01 will work`. You can get the values using regex or the methods in the `location` object. Please note that those options are not how they intend to be used. So side effects can occur.

Comment: Instead of passing it as a parameter, also consider passing them identifier in the path `site-ce207.firebaseapp.com/company/01`. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish with this URL, the latter may be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mouser pointed out, this is invalid:

```
site-ce207.firebaseapp.com/company=01
```

However, this isnt:

```
site-ce207.firebaseapp.com#company=01&id=5
```

And it can be easily parsed:

```
var queries=location.hash.slice(1).split("&").map(el=>el.split("="));
```

Queries now.looks like this:

```
[
["company","01"],
["id","5"]
]
```

So to resolve it may do use an object:

```
var getQuery={};
queries.forEach(query=>getQuery[query[0]]=query[1]);
```

So now its easy to get a certain key:

```
console.log(getQuery["company"]);
```

Or new and more easy using a Map:

```
var query=new Map(queries);
console.log(query.get("company"));
```

Comment: Worked Great! Just one thing: Since company is the first item it is "#company" instead of "company". So solved by query.get("#company").

Comment: Please edit you question without arrowed functions, since they are not common yet.

Comment: @Mouser the requirenment is JS, not ES5. If the OP really wants to work with it online, he/she should use babel

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple function I found a long time ago to handle this. I modified a bit to get the value by doing this.

```
function param(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and then to use the value I do the following

```
var myCity = param('cityid');
```

when issuing something like: http://example.com/?cityid=Guatemala

myCity will have the value of 'Guatemala' in my app.